# How to import MySQL databases with indexes and foreign keys using phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I exported my db on my localhost (XAMPP) using PHPMyAdmin, I'm using a Mac, and it had all of the indexes and Foreign Keys on all of the tables. I deleted my db, and now every time I import it back, there's no Unique key for example, there used to be one on every id column in every table and now there's nothing.

I'm using Laravel, so I could just Migrate my tables again and reseed my application, but I was working with the dummy data for a while and I want this to be my last resort.

I'm wondering if I'm importing the db incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

So my .sql file that I exported, contained the sql code at the bottom for adding all of the keys and indexes to all of my Tables. I simply copy and pasted that code into the SQL editor tab in phpmyadmin and it worked, everything got added back. This is a quick solution, I'm not sure why they didn't get imported when I imported the database file. It might be an issue with incompatible SQL versions on my localhost and on my Hosting company.